# Remove all child from node with the same class, pure js

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove all elements with a certain class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842471/remove-all-elements-with-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

As title, google search gives me all jquery results. Is there a method that does this? ex.

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="dontdelete">...</div>
   <div class="deleteme>...</div>
   <div class="dontdelete">...</div>
   <div class="deleteme>...</div>
   <div class="dontdelete">...</div>
   <div class="deleteme>...</div>
</div>
```

Is there a method in pure javascript to delete all child with "deleteme" class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specifically on the question linked above, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842510/541091

Comment: Yes, maybe when I was googling I refer as 'child' so that post didn't pop up.

Comment: It's ok - I actually had to search pretty carefully to find an appropriate question to link to. There are _many_ related jQuery questions, but not many plain JS.

Comment: a lot more code than $('#container .deleteme').remove(); though. jQuery is your friend! So is google.

Comment: @popnoodles: At least use `#container > .deleteme` :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `element.getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** node list, you need to loop through the list in a certain way (since removing them from the DOM removes them from the list as well). Try something like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var elements = container.getElementsByClassName("deleteme");

while (elements[0]) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sR2zT/1/

Or you could use something like `element.querySelectorAll` to select the elements, where you can do things like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#container .deleteme")
// or
document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll(".deleteme")
```

In this scenario, you **don't** need to do *special* looping, because `querySelectorAll` doesn't contain a **live** node list.

**References:**

- `getElementsByClassName()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName
- `querySelectorAll()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll
- `removeChild()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) to get all your elements. Then you can use something like [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) to delete the nodes.

```
​var elements = document.getElementById("container")
                   .getElementsByClassName("deleteme");    ​​​

while (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ja4Zt/1/

**Browser support:**

The only caveat with this solution is that it has limited support in IE. According to [this table](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname), `getElementsByClassName` was implemented in IE as of version 9.

To bridge this, you could select all nodes that are child of the element with ID container, loop over them and check if they have the class "deleteme", and only then delete them.

Comment: This isn't fully correct - your fiddle throws an error (if you actually close the quotes in your HTML). This is because the `getElementsByClassName` returns a live node list of matches. So when you loop from 0 to its length and remove the element (which affects the actual list), the item is actually removed from the list as well and you get an out-of-bounds error. Try using a while loop or for looping from its length to 0.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, I didn't think of that! Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This version avoids having to use `.getElementsByClassName()` which as others have mentioned is not supported in certain IE versions.

```
var divs = document.getElementById("container").childNodes;
var i = divs.length;
while( i-- ) {
    if( divs[i].className && divs[i].className.indexOf("deleteme") > -1 ) {
      divs[i].parentNode.removeChild( divs[i] );
    }
}​
```

This also traverses the resulting array backwards so deleting nodes doesn't affect the next iteration.

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BShu4/1/)

Comment: I don't mind the downvote but it might be nice to know why even if it is just so I don't make the mistake of using the above in the future :)

Comment: I didn't vote, but your `--i` should be `i--`. The way it is right now, you'll always be skipping the first item in the collection. http://jsfiddle.net/BShu4/2/

Comment: @user1689607 Thank you for giving me a chance to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteme");
for (var idx = 0; idx != divs.length; idx++) {
  var div = divs[idx];
  while (div.firstChild)
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

​

Comment: that will get all elements in the document with the class, not those just in #container

Comment: @popnoodles that wasn't specified in the question.