# Use Javascript to remove a div from DOM without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently using jQuery to remove a div, but I'd like my project to not have to rely on a third party library for it to work. Say my div had the class .main, if I was using jQuery I'd write:

```
$("div.main").remove()
```

How would I do this with JS only?

Comment: Come on, use the search. Is it so hard?

Comment: I did use the search

Comment: No, you didn't. There are hundreds of questions with this topic on Stackoverflow and thousands of tutorials, blog posts, documentation pages and whatnot on the wider Internet. They would have been impossible to miss, if you only had tried half as long as it took you to write down this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate question but try this: (Set an id for it)

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

**or take a look at this topic:**

[Remove all elements of a certain class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842471/remove-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't .remove(); Require jQuery? No it didn't work.

Comment: I'm lost at the parentNode bit, sorry @jiff

Comment: @Verpz see this example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/wk7qvv0q/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

IE8+