# Remove HTML Element by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've created a simple banner that sits above my navigation. And i want to give my users the chance to close this banner any time.

That's the banner right now:

[image]

```
     <div class="header-top discord">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="discordbanner">
          <p class="pull-left">Join our <img style="width:125px" src="assets\images\random\discord.svg"/> Server today and connect with other...!</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-yellow pull-right">Join our Discord!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And i want to have something like a simple button with an X to indicate that this element can be closed.

Thats how it should look like:

[image]

So basically i want to delete the ID **header-top discord** and its content with a simple close button.
Via JS or jquery doesn't really matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An important part of the questions here are showing your attempts at resolving them yourself. What have you tried?

Comment: Would be nice if there were a remove method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all elements of a certain class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842471/remove-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

JQuery: `$(".header-top discord").remove();`

You can call this on a button click

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".header-top discord").remove();
});
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName("header-top discord")[0];
if (node.firstChild) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

References:
[MDN - removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) 
[Remove all elements of a certain class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842471/remove-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

Comment: But i still need an on click handler.

Comment: do all the things for me

Comment: @Leeooh, you may have a look at `JQuery` and `Javascript` implementation. You won't need any event handler for javascript here.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">X</button>
```

Pure JS:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var headerClass = document.querySelector('.header-top discord');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   headerClass.style.display="none";
});
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   $('.header-top discord').hide(); //puts display: none; to styles
});
```

But I prefer `.fadeOut('slow');` for these occasions.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to hide the banner:

```
$('.header-top discord').hide();
```

Comment: does this behave like css' `visibility: hidden;`?

Comment: This will apply the inline style display:none; therefore it will remove any space occupied by the banner.