# Remove All Elements with the Same Class in Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that is being validated once the user clicks submit. If there is an error, a `<span>` tag with the class `message` is displayed above each input field that is empty. When the user makes the correction and clicks submit again, I want all the `message` classes to be removed that way I can validate the inputs again without having to worry about duplicating the error messages.

### HTML

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column is-6--tablet">
    <h2>Personal Information</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <span class="message">Please enter your first name.</span>
        <label for="xFIRST_NAME">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="text" name="xFIRST_NAME" value="<?php echo $xFIRST_NAME; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <span class="message">Please enter your last name.</span>
        <label for="xLAST_NAME">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="text" name="xLAST_NAME" value="<?php echo $xLAST_NAME; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
       <span class="message">Please enter your phone.</span>
        <label for="XPHONE">Phone</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="tel" name="xPHONE" value="<?php echo $xPHONE; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <label for="xEMAIL">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="email" name="xEMAIL" value="<?php echo $xEMAIL; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row patient-type">
      <div class="column is-12">
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="xPATIENT_STATUS" id="NEW_PATIENT" value="New Patient" <?php echo ($xPATIENT_STATUS === 'New Patient' ? 'checked' : ''); ?> required>
        <label for="NEW_PATIENT">&nbsp;New Patient</label>
        <input type="radio" name="xPATIENT_STATUS" id="EXISTING_PATIENT" value="Existing Patient" <?php echo ($xPATIENT_STATUS === 'Existing Patient' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>
        <label for="EXISTING_PATIENT">&nbsp;Existing Patient</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
for(var i = 0; 1 < messages.length; i++)
{
  messages[i].parentNode.removeChild(messages[i]);
}
```

The error I am getting says `TypeError: messages[i] is undefined`

How can I query all the classes `message` and remove them?I have seen similar questions on here but none of them seem to answer what I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all elements of a certain class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842471/remove-all-elements-of-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

Comment: But... what's not working about your current code?

Comment: So it works; however I am receiving an error `TypeError: messages[i] is undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `for(var i = 0; 1 < messages.length; i++)` but the `1` should be your variable named `i` instead.  like this: `for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)`

Right now your code reads "keep looping if the number 1 is less than the number of messages"

```js
var messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
{
  messages[i].parentNode.removeChild(messages[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column is-6--tablet">
    <h2>Personal Information</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <span class="message">Please enter your first name.</span>
        <label for="xFIRST_NAME">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="text" name="xFIRST_NAME" value="<?php echo $xFIRST_NAME; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <span class="message">Please enter your last name.</span>
        <label for="xLAST_NAME">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="text" name="xLAST_NAME" value="<?php echo $xLAST_NAME; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
       <span class="message">Please enter your phone.</span>
        <label for="XPHONE">Phone</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="tel" name="xPHONE" value="<?php echo $xPHONE; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column is-3">
        <label for="xEMAIL">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="column is-9">
        <input type="email" name="xEMAIL" value="<?php echo $xEMAIL; ?>" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row patient-type">
      <div class="column is-12">
        <hr>
        <input type="radio" name="xPATIENT_STATUS" id="NEW_PATIENT" value="New Patient" <?php echo ($xPATIENT_STATUS === 'New Patient' ? 'checked' : ''); ?> required>
        <label for="NEW_PATIENT">&nbsp;New Patient</label>
        <input type="radio" name="xPATIENT_STATUS" id="EXISTING_PATIENT" value="Existing Patient" <?php echo ($xPATIENT_STATUS === 'Existing Patient' ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>
        <label for="EXISTING_PATIENT">&nbsp;Existing Patient</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typos are common enough, and so unlikely to help others, that there is a specific close reason for them. Adding a comment is sufficient.

Comment: wow! I can't believed I missed that typo. So simple! Thank you

Comment: Good point, I wasn't aware that was the preferred way to deal with questions like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You simply have a typo in your for statement, replace `1` with `i` in the predicate

```
var messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  messages[i].parentNode.removeChild(messages[i]);
}
```

Also note, you could use `messages[i].remove()` for shorter syntax. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove))

Comment: `.remove()` is not supported everywhere, so unfortunately the other way is actually the way to get it working everywhere

Comment: In the future, rather than submitting an answer to solely correct typos, please leave a comment and vote to close. There's a specific "Vote To Close" option specifically for them: *"Off Topic > Simple Typographical Error"*. That way, OP gets their answer and their code is fixed, but future readers aren't digging through clutter to get to more meaningful and helpful posts!

Answer (score 3):

I see an error in your foor loop. `1 < messages.length` is probably always true. Replace `1` with `i`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
{
  messages[i].parentNode.removeChild(messages[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right:

```
var messages = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
for(var i = 0; 1 < messages.length; i++)
{
  messages[i].classList.remove('message');
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to remove the class from the node, but to remove the node itself from the DOM.